# Run mapreduce Code on specific named files

Tags: python, hadoop

I need to run a top 10 word count program on files located in a certain folder in Hadoop. The code to run the program is as follows

```
[training@localhost map_reduce]$ /opt/anaconda351/bin/python word_count_top_max.py /home/training/training_materials/data/kb
```

The python program is in the map_reduce folder which is why I'm in that directory and it's being run on the folder outlined after it. I now need to run this program on the same folder, but only on files that have "30" in the filename. I've tried the following, but have had no luck and am banging my head against a wall now. Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
[training@localhost map_reduce]$ /opt/anaconda351/bin/python word_count_top_max.py | ls -d *30* /home/training/training_materials/data/kb
```

Comment: Can you please show your script? Is there anything against using pyspark?